# Selenium 2 - Can't click on menu

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I use WebDriver, and everything works great in firefox.

My problem is with IE8 - Everthing work O.K, but in some cases, It doesn't find the element. As I understood it, it happen because the webdriver, for some reason, maximaize and minimaize the IE browser before every operation. So it open the menu, but then maximaize the browser, and the menu closed - so It doesn't find the element which is in the menu.

How I can cancel this option of max and min the IE browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason the IE driver would change the size of the browser window without you explicitly telling it to do so is if you're taking screenshots of the page. You haven't mentioned this, but I'm going to use my psychic debugging powers to guess that your framework must be taking screenshots before every operation. Don't take a screenshot before every operation, and that behavior should stop.

Before you ask, no, you can't stop the IE driver from doing this when taking screenshots. Taking a screenshot in WebDriver is defined as taking rendering of the full DOM, which requires a window resize in IE. It's a limitation of IE; there's nothing the driver can do about it.